# Calculate real width based on picture, knowing distance

Tags: ios, math, ios-camera

I know the distance between the camera and the object

I know the type of camera used

I know the width in pixel on the picture

Can I figure the real life width of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you have to get the angle of camera. For example, iphone 5s is 61.4 in vertical and 48.0 horizontal. call it alpha.
2. then you calculate the width of object by this way:

   viewWidth = distance * tan(alpha / 2) * 2;

   objWidth = viewWidth * (imageWidth / screenWidth)

Comment: thanks!
how/where did you find the camera angle? I'm trying to figure it for an ipad mini 2, however I can't seem to find any information (focal length/sensor size)

Comment: You can search about that on google. you can see a lot of people public iphone's camera specification. of course that sometime we can accept a round number of that (iphone and ipad just have a sightly different)